# What's different btw color.status.added and color.status.updated for git config?

Tags: git

I currently changed my git config color.

As I can see [git docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#git-config-colorstatus), I can change `color.status` using few slots.

> Use customized color for status colorization.  is one of header (the header text of the status message), **added or updated (files which are added but not committed)**, changed (files which are changed but not added in the index), untracked (files which are not tracked by Git), branch (the current branch), nobranch (the color the no branch warning is shown in, defaulting to red), localBranch or remoteBranch (the local and remote branch names, respectively, when branch and tracking information is displayed in the status short-format), or unmerged (files which have unmerged changes).

I wonder the difference between `added` and `updated` above.

So I tried both using `git config color.status.added <color>` and `git config color.status.updated <color>`.

For me, only `updated` works and I can't find any difference in `added` command.

Could anyone know the difference? When I can use `added`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the docs: "*added* **OR** *updated* is for files which are added but not committed".

The following code is from git version [v2.18.0](https://github.com/git/git/blob/53f9a3e157dbbc901a02ac2c73346d375e24978c/builtin/commit.c#L1192). It shows that there is indeed no difference between `"updated"` and `"added"`.

```c
static int parse_status_slot(const char *slot)
{
    ...
    if (!strcasecmp(slot, "updated") || !strcasecmp(slot, "added"))
        return WT_STATUS_UPDATED;
    if (!strcasecmp(slot, "changed"))
        return WT_STATUS_CHANGED;
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I didn't try to find github code before. Now I can find inside there, great! I just curious why `added` not work. Anyway thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

For `git status`, the `color.status.added` and `color.status.updated` slots have the same meaning.  In fact, internally, any reference to `color.status.added` is just translated into a reference to the value of `color.status.updated`.

In other words, these are just synonyms.  Set whichever spelling you prefer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Then why `added` not working in my working context? I figured out that only `updated` works with git config command

Comment: Git's config files are handled one line at a time, so whichever setting you set *second* is the one that will take effect.